# Is the .nuget folder redundant

Tags: .net, visual-studio, azure-devops, nuget

Is the .nuget folder still needed? It seems that some solutions are unable to add nuget packages without the .nuget folder in place.
Using Visual Studio 2017 and Azure Devops.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that `.nuget` folder with the `NuGet.targets` is how NuGet was "integrated" into Visual Studio before Visual Studio 2015, which is to say it basically didn't at all. It just used MSBuild extensibility to automatically run `nuget.exe restore <project_name>.csproj` on every build. From VS2015, NuGet is more integrated with Visual Studio, which has performance benefits, and gives you the option to turn off automatic restore in VS options.

NuGet's docs has steps to [migrate to automatic package restore (Visual Studio)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-restore#migrate-to-automatic-package-restore-visual-studio), or as I like to describe it "undo the damage". Basically, delete the `.nuget` folder and edit all your project files to remove any reference to it. Unfortunately there is no tool created by the NuGet team to automate this.